# The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Function'. Try correcting the name to a name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'

Tags: flutter, dart

I do not know why but the method map is wrong. Can someone please help me with this issue?

```
import 'package:pwff/models/user.dart' as models;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

   models.User? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? models.User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<models.User> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`authStateChanges` is a function, so you need to call it first, like this:

```
  Stream<models.User> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

Comment: @Destroyer00000 why did you remove the acceptance of the answer? Something not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<models.User> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser!);
}
```

Try the above code instead

Answer (score 0):

Stream<UserLogin?> get user {

```
return _auth.authStateChanges()
```

.map(_userFromFireBaseUser);
}
use ? This is useful if you want null aware returns.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).